# How to pass a 2D array to a function using single pointer

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

I want to pass a 2D array to a function . I must receive the 2D array using a single pointer in the formal argument.

Comment: If you have `int arr[3][8];`, then your parameter is `int (*)[8]`. (*pointer-to-array of* `int[8]`)

Answer (score 2):

In C when you have a 2D array, you have an *array of 1D arrays*. On access, an array is converted to a pointer to its first element. [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) For an *array of arrays* it is a pointer to the first *array*. So your pointer is a *pointer-to-array* of `type[DIM]` (where `DIM` is the dimension of the array.

For example if you have an array of integers, e.g. `int arr[3][5];`, then on access you have a *pointer-to-array* of `int[5]`. The formal type is `int (*)[5]`.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLS 5

/* print the contents of a 2d array */
void prn2d (int (*a)[COLS], int rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            printf (" %2d", a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}

int main (void) {
    
    int arr[][COLS] = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                        {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
                        {11, 12, 13, 14, 15} },
        n = sizeof arr/sizeof *arr;
    
    prn2d (arr, n);     /* pass arr to your function */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/pass2darr
  1  2  3  4  5
  6  7  8  9 10
 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: Yes this is how we generally do, but the OP says "I must receive the 2D array using a single pointer in the formal argument."

Comment: `int (*a)[COLS]` is a *Single Pointer*. You either pass the number of rows -- or use a *Sentinel* to mark the end of the array. You can use a *Sentinel* `NULL` with a *pointer-to-pointer* -- but that has nothing to do with an Array.

Comment: "``int (*a)[COLS]`` is a Single Pointer" -- But pointer arithmetic of this kind (``a[i][j]``) suggests that ``a`` is double-pointer, Is'nt it?

Comment: This could be what the OP expects but still this is syntactical sugar for a pointer to pointer.

Comment: No. `a[i][j]` is simply removing 2 levels of *indirection* from whatever the current pointer is. `a[i][j]` = `*(*(a + i) + j)`, and so on...  Whether the level of indirection is due to an `array` or a `pointer` depends on the type and does not imply a *pointer-to-pointer* necessarily. A *pointer-to-pointer* is separate and distinct from a *pointer-to-array*. With a *pointer-to-pointer* `p + 1` advances to the next *pointer*. With a *pointer-to-array*, `p + 1` advances to the next *Array*.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char* str_arr, int m, int n)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                printf("%s ", str_arr + n * i);
        }

        printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
        char str_arr[5][7] = {"But,", "what", "is", "the", "point?"};

        func((char*) str_arr, 5, 7);

        return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
But, what is the point?
```

And the output is my question (- -)

Comment: OT: do not use leading underscores in variable names,

Comment: @user3629249 Can I know why :( I even saw many libraries using such declarations...

Comment: the compiler prepends a leading underscore to all items that go into the symbol table and all labels in the generated assembly code, except local labels

Comment: why write code that you do not know what it is doing?

Comment: regarding the expression: `sizeof(char)`  this is defined in the C standard as 1.  Therefore, it makes no difference in the resulting offset to the array:  `str_arr[[][]`.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: @user3629249 "the compiler prepends a leading underscore to all items that go into the symbol table and all labels in the generated assembly code, except local labels" -- My knowledge didn't reach that extent, as you suggested I removed it. "why write code that you do not know what it is doing?" I am very well aware of what my code is doing, but I don't know the need of the OP for doing such a thing (maybe it is an interview question). "Therefore, it makes no difference in the resulting offset to the array:" -- Edited.

Comment: You have to be somewhat careful here. Masking a 2D array with a (cast) will lead to a technical violation of [C11 Standard - 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1). In `func` you access beyond the 6th element which subscripts beyond the bounds of the first array in the 2D array. While arrays are contiguous in memory, the limts on subscripting still apply.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "In func you access beyond the 6th element" -- You mean with this line of code ``printf("%s ", str_arr + n * i);`` Ha yes, if the 6th element (when counted from 0) or before is not ``0`` then ``printf()`` reads beyond the bounds. But even in ``main()`` if you write something like this, ``printf("%s", str_arr[0])`` issue still remains, I think user should be careful about the array sizes and string ``nul`` termination.

Comment: Yes, this is more one of those "technical" things. A 2D array, being an array of 1D arrays, requires that each 1D array be properly accessed by subscripts within the declared bounds. Now you and I both know that arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory, so you have a block of memory of `rows * cols * sizeof (type)` bytes. When you cast away the `column` information and then subscript the array from `0 -> rows * cols * sizeof (type)`, you subscript past the end of the 1st array (and all other arrays as your index is now beyond the bounds of all 1D arrays included). It woks, but...

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
printf("%s ", str_arr + sizeof(char) * n * i);
```

slightly rewritten:

```
printf("%s ", &str_arr[n * i];
```

shows that the code is stepping through the memory occupied by the array `str_arr[][]`  and the 'output conversion' specifier `%s` is saying to output the string, starting at `str_arr[0]` and treating the whole array as a single contiguous set of bytes.  where the second iteration of the loop accesses `str_arr[7]` and the third iteration of the loop accesses `str_arr[14]`  etc.